# Можно ли использовать местоимения в дипломной работе?

Tags: местоимения

Можно ли использовать местоимения в дипломной работе?
Какие? При каких обстоятельствах?
И если да, можно ссылку на ГОСТ, подтверждающий это.

Например: "Так как для управления двигателями нельзя использовать подключение к микроконтроллеру напрямую, иначе **его** порт сгорит..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно конечно. Местоимения — это неотъемлемая часть языка и использовать их можно и нужно. Можете найти в Сети автореферат защищенной докторской или кандидатской диссертации по вашей науке, и там обязательно найдете местоимения.

Единственно, в русской научной традиции не принято "якать". Все предложения с местоимением "я" (кроме цитат) следует заменить на безличные; если это невозможно, допустимо говорить о себе в третьем лице (автор данной работы) или во множественном числе (мы), подразумевая, что при прочтении доказательств и вы, и читатель, и научный руководитель должны прийти к одинаковому выводу.

Все остальные местоимения допустимы, главное, чтобы при этом текст сохранял однозначность.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать. Все слова русского языка можете использовать, кроме нецензурных и просторечных. Местоимения к ним не относятся.

ГОСТами такие вещи не регламентируются.